# Reduce Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to understand the raw codes of the reduce function and how to use it.

```
    var each = function(collection, callback){
        if(Array.isArray(collection)){
            for(var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
                callback(collection[i]);
            }
        }
        else{
            for(var key in collection){
                callback(collection[key]);
            }
        }
    };

var reduce = function(collection, callback, accumulator){
  each(collection, function(element){
    if(accumulator === undefined) {
      return accumulator = element;
    }else {
      return accumulator = callback(accumulator, element);
    };
});

return accumulator;
};

var sArr = [3, 2, 3, 4, 5];


each(sArr, function(collection){
  console.log(collection);
});

reduce(sArr, function(collection, prev){
  console.log(prev = prev + sArr);
});
```

On my codes above as you can see I was trying to reduce all of my arrays into one element by adding them all up just like a normal reduce function does but it doesn't work the way I think it is.

Can somebody check if I am doing wrong and if you can explain to me in layman's term what does my reduce function does line by line?

Sorry newbie.

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting? (I'm guessing you probably want your `reduce` function to actually return a value at the end)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @JosiahKeller: I am getting a series of nubmersinstead of reduce one number: "21,2,3,4,5"

Comment: If you're getting that, then whatever you're running is different from what you gave us, since your code can only produce `ReferenceError: myArr is not defined`. Make sure what you're testing is actually what you posted. :)

Comment: Edited. sorry my bad.

Comment: That *displays* `23,2,3,4,5` and `43,2,3,4,5`, but *returns* `5`: on the first iteration `accumulator` is `undefined` so it becomes `5`; the next pass, accumulator is set to `undefined` (because nothing is returned from `callback`); third pass, `accumulator` is undefined again so it becomes `3` (the third element); fourth pass, `undefined` again; fifth pass, reinitialised to `5` (the fifth element). Callback is executed just two times, on second and fourth pass, and that's when you get your two `console.log` with current element string-concatenated to the array `sArr` (always `sArr`).

Comment: @Amadan: I tried your solution but it doesnt log me anyting on my end.

Comment: You should implement `each` in terms of `reduce`, not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reduce(sArr, function(collection, prev){
  return collection + prev;
});
```

or equivalently

```
reduce(sArr, (collection, prev) => collection + prev);
```

will return the correct value. What you have:

```
reduce(sArr, function(collection, prev){
  console.log(prev = prev + myArr);
});
```

will try to add non-existent value (`myArr`) to the current element, then try to assign it back to the local variable (`prev`) that will be discarded at the end of the function, then display it, and finally return `undefined` to the accumulator because you don't have a `return` function.

Comment: tried this: reduce(sArr, function(collection, prev){
  return collection + prev;
}); but it doesnt give me anything on the console log.

Comment: There is no `console.log` in `reduce(sArr, function(collection, prev){ return collection + prev; });`. Did you try `console.log(reduce(sArr, function(collection, prev){ return collection + prev; }));`? Because that prints `17`.

Comment: I think it works now. Thanks for that. Btw, I am a new beginner to this one. Mind trying to explain what my reduce function does line by line please? I am a dummy.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it without literally reading the code out loud line by line: it will iterate on `collection`, taking each `element` in turn; if `accumulator` is `undefined` (hopefully the first element when `accumulator` parameter wasn't passed) it will set it to the current element, otherwise it will set it to the result of applying `callback` to `accumulator` and `element`. There is a bug if `callback` returns `undefined` (`accumulator` gets set to the next element, effectively resetting the procedure mid-`collection`) that your code triggers, which JS `reduce` wouldn't do.

Comment: do you think i need to explicitly declare return undefined?